# color is not loaded from firebase remote config

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-remote-config

Hi I'm using webview and I want to dynamically change the title color in the menu. However, this does not happen with a hot reload. What am I doing wrong?

```
final labelColor = Colors.orange;



final FirebaseRemoteConfig _remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
  Future<void> _initConfig() async {
    await _remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
      fetchTimeout: const Duration(
          seconds: 1), // a fetch will wait up to 10 seconds before timing out
      minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(
          seconds:
              10), // fetch parameters will be cached for a maximum of 1 hour
    ));

    await _fetchConfig();
    setState(() {});
  }

  // Fetching, caching, and activating remote config
  Future <void> _fetchConfig() async {
    await _remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initConfig();
    super.initState();
  }
```

And here is the code of my menu where I am trying to change the color

```
selectedItemColor: _remoteConfig.getString('labelColor').isNotEmpty ? _remoteConfig.getString('labelColor') as Color : labelColor,
```

key in Firebase - [image: key and value in firebase]

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild state after fetching data.

Try this.

```
Future<void> _initConfig() async {
    await _remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
      fetchTimeout: const Duration(
          seconds: 1), // a fetch will wait up to 10 seconds before timing out
      minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(
          seconds:
              10), // fetch parameters will be cached for a maximum of 1 hour
    ));

    await _fetchConfig();
     setState((){}); <--------------------- add this here

  }
```

Make `_fetchConfig` return type `Future<void>`.

```
Future<void> _fetchConfig() async {
    await _remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
  }
```

Comment: i get error - FirebaseException ([firebase_remote_config/internal] internal remote config fetch error)